# JavaScript window namespacing - could I get some insight into what this is doing please?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, coffeescript, javascript-namespaces

I have some code that I am struggling to understand. I'm no expert in JavaScript (I have a basic grasp), and I've been reading about the DOM and namespacing (and `console.log()`'ing the variables) to try and get my head around what this is doing (unfortunately to no avail).

This code is way beyond my understanding and I was hoping someone could "dumb it down" for me with an explanation of what it does.

This is the coffeescript (I'll put the JavaScript at the end):

```
((window) ->
    'use strict'
    window.__slice = [].slice
    namespace = (target, name, block) ->
        [target, name, block] = [window, arguments...] if arguments.length < 3
        top = target
        target = target[item] or= {} for item in name.split '.'
        block target, top
    namespace 'my_app', (exports, top) ->
        exports.namespace = namespace
)(window)
```

I understand that it's managing namespacing and that it's an IIFE. My thoughts on the rest (but very unsure):

1. `window.__slice = [].slice` - no idea what this is meant to do.
2. `namespace = (target, name, block) ->` - defines a function and it's parameters
3. `namespace 'my_app', (exports, top) ->` - calling the `namespace` function, with `target='my_app'`. The second parameter being passed in is a function that seems to return a single variable (instead of the two required by the `namespace` function). I don't understand why this works if `namespace` defines 3 parameters. It makes sense if `namespace = (target='my_app', name='exports', block='top')`, I just don't see how it's getting there through `return exports.namespace = namespace`.

If I could get some insight into what 1 and 3 are doing, I think I could figure out the rest, but if you could lend some insight into the code as a whole it would be greatly appreciated.

JavaScript (converted with [coffee2js](https://awsm-tools.com/code/coffee2js)):

```
(function() {
  var __slice = [].slice;

  (function(window) {
    'use strict';
    var namespace;
    window.__slice = [].slice;
    namespace = function(target, name, block) {
      var item, top, _i, _len, _ref, _ref1;
      if (arguments.length < 3) {
        _ref = [window].concat(__slice.call(arguments)), target = _ref[0], name = _ref[1], block = _ref[2];
      }
      top = target;
      _ref1 = name.split('.');
      for (_i = 0, _len = _ref1.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
        item = _ref1[_i];
        target = target[item] || (target[item] = {});
      }
      return block(target, top);
    };
    return namespace('my_app', function(exports, top) {
      return exports.namespace = namespace;
    });
  })(window);

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer the 3 question:

**1.- Slice**

**slice()** is a builtin method of all arrays in js. It is used to copy an array, getting a new array not a reference to the original array (in js, arrays are copied by reference by default)

The line `window.__slice = [].slice` is creating a new method, in the window, called `__slice`, and it's value is a copy of the native js method `slice`.

Later it's used here: `__slice.call(arguments)`

Take a look to [slice docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

**2.- Functions**

`namespace = (target, name, block) ->`

You are right, it's coffeescript syntax, and it will produce a regular function and it's parameters.

**3.- Functions and arguments**

Quoting: "I don't understand why this works if namespace defines 3 parameters...."

All regular functions (not arrow functions) have a built-in object called `arguments`.

It is used here:

```
if (arguments.length < 3) {...}
```

In this way, you can check the number of arguments of your function.

Check the [arguments docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Finally, in my opinion, if you are not very familiar with javascript, you should try to learn the syntax of vanilla js, not coffeescript. Besides, coffeescript is less used every day.